# Como optimizar la carga de imagenes en django

Tags: python, django, optimización, model

Hola estoy tratando de crear una pagina web en la cual tengo que tener unas imagenes, mi problema es que al subir las imagens estas se demoran muchisimo en cargar, quisiera saber alguna manera de solucionar esto.

El metodo que ocupe es este:

En models.py tengo una clase que recibe un models.ImageField(), los modelos estan conectados a una base de datos sqlite3, las imagenes recibidas son cargadas en una carpeta media.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    SHIRT_SIZES = (
        ('S', 'Small'),
        ('M', 'Medium'),
        ('L', 'Large'),
        ('XL', 'Extra-Large'),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    talla = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=SHIRT_SIZES)
    precio = models.IntegerField()
    tipo = models.ForeignKey(ProductType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="productos")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='shop/images', blank=True, null=True)
```

Para cargar la imagen en views.py tengo una funcion que primero que hace es buscar el tipo de producto que se nececita, una vez encontrado se envia la lista de productos de ese tipo al html

```
def productos(request, product_type):
    tipo_producto = ProductType.objects.get(tipo=product_type)
    context = {'productos': Product.objects.filter(tipo = tipo_producto),
    'product_type': product_type}

    return render(request, "shop/productos.html", context)
```

Por ultimo el html carga las imagenes de la siguiente manera:

```
{% extends "shop/base.html "%}


{% block title %}
{{ product_type }}
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
<h1>Welcome to the Shop madafacka!!</h1>

<ul>
    {% for producto in productos %}
    <li>
        {{ producto }} {{producto.precio}}$

        <img src="{{ producto.image }}" alt="">
    </li>
    {% endfor %}

</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: No parece que tengas un problema grave de rendimiento a nivel de código. ¿No tienes suficiente ancho de banda para servir las imágenes? -> Contrata más caudal si es posible. ¿Las imágenes son muy pesadas? -> Baja la calidad de las imágenes si es posible ¿Son muchas las imágenes en la base de datos? -> Realiza paginado de los resultados e invierte en otro motor de base de datos si es posible.